# How do I move tables and indexes owned by user to new tablespaces in Oracle 19C?

Tags: oracle, tablespaces

I have a user named SDE and the tablespace for this users tables are in SDE_TBS, I would like to move all of these tables to tablespace SDEBUS_DT.  For indexes I would like to move to SDEBUS_IX.  How would I accomplish this? I have reference [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327671/how-to-move-table-from-one-tablespace-to-another-in-oracle-11g) thread, but it does not address my question completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do easily (assuming you have the appropriate permissions) is to invoke the PL/SQL procedure [DBMS_REDEFINITION.REDEF_TABLE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_REDEFINITION.html#GUID-3E72906F-0A2D-4970-B299-DDBCC32CB5D3) which you can use to change things such as tablespaces for data and for indexes.  Here is a snippet of code for moving a table named `MY_DATA_TABLE`.  To do several, you would need to invoke it once per table.

```
begin
    DBMS_REDEFINITION.REDEF_TABLE(
        uname=>'SDE'
        , tname=>'MY_DATA_TABLE'
        , table_part_tablespace=>'SDEBUS_DT'
        , index_tablespace=>'SDEBUS_IX'
   );

end;
/
```

But before you begin, just check to see if your `SDE` owner has permissions on the tablespaces `SDEBUS_DT` and `SDEBUS_IX` first.  Also, if those commands are invoked by the `SDE` user, that user will need `CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE MVIEW` privileges.

Now if you want to loop through several tables, run a SQL like the following, which will display the commands to copy/paste.  Yes, you could do the following in a PL/SQL loop, but I don't do that often enough to remember which of the 3 or 4 ways to do that, without looking it up!

```
-- omit the "execute" if you want to run the following output
--  in a BEGIN/END block instead of running each line, one at a time.

select 'execute DBMS_REDEFINITION.REDEF_TABLE(uname=>''' || 
    owner || ''', tname=>' ||
    '''' || table_name || '''' ||
    ', table_part_tablespace=>''SDEBUS_DT'' , index_tablespace=>''SDEBUS_IX'');' as cmd from dba_tables where owner='MARK.STEWART';

CMD
---------------------------------------------------------
execute DBMS_REDEFINITION.REDEF_TABLE(uname=>'MARK.STEWART', tname=>'DBMSHP_RUNS', table_part_tablespace=>'SDEBUS_DT' , index_tablespace=>'SDEBUS_IX');
execute DBMS_REDEFINITION.REDEF_TABLE(uname=>'MARK.STEWART', tname=>'DBMSHP_FUNCTION_INFO', table_part_tablespace=>'SDEBUS_DT' , index_tablespace=>'SDEBUS_IX');
```

Comment: It would be fairly easy to wrap that in a loop to bounce through all tables  owned by `SDE` in the "old" tablespace.  Leave a comment if you need some direction there.

Comment: Hi @Mark Stewart - I do need some direction here.

Comment: Updated answer above to show an example loop.  Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use simple `ALTER TABLE/INDEX` command

```
for aTab in (select table_name from dba_tables where owner = 'SDE') loop
   execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE SDE.' ||aTab.table_name|| ' MOVE TABLESPACE SDEBUS_DT';
end loop;

for aInd in (select index_name from dba_indexes where owner = 'SDE') loop
   execute immediate 'ALTER INDEX SDE.' ||aInd.index_name|| ' REBUILD TABLESPACE SDEBUS_IX';
end loop;
```

But `DBMS_REDEFINITION.REDEF_TABLE` is more versatile than `ALTER TABLE/INDEX`, e.g. when user has partitioned tables.